# questions about singularities and complex functions having poles of order k , proofs and examples

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

1)i need an example of a non isolated singularity

2) also i need an entire function which assumes every complex value but the number 1+2i
and i want to know the way in order to solve some other questions i have

3) how do i describe the singularity at z= infinity
for example at the function 
f(z)= exp(z)/(z^2 +1)
f(z)= (z^2 +1)/exp(z)

4) for f(z) a polynomial =sum (an z^n) of order k
can i prove that it has a pole of order k at z=infinity?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 take something like 
$$\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}$$
For 2, you know that $\exp$ is entire and $\exp(z)\neq 0$, think how that helps.
For 3, you just definie $z=\frac{1}{w}$ and then $z\to \infty$ is the same as $\frac{1}{w}\to 0$. (at least when you go on the real axis)

For 4, just use the definition of a pole of order $k$.